# Retrieving data from XMLHttpRequest on $.Ajax Error Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

As the title says, i want to retrieve my Json data values from a XMLHttpRequest. I already know how to do it by using a common success $.Ajax success event, but i want to get it's values from an error event. A thing that i noticed is not simple to find all kinds of a XMLHttpRequest types.

To explain a little more, here's the scenario: after some inactivity, the user sessions expires. If he tries to do any operations using an Ajax call, he'll be redirected to the login page. I handle this session timeout error on a particular filter that implements an OnException method.

While i can do it using a sort of a hack (by setting manually the HTTP response code), i'd like to do it on "proper way", with no hacks.

**OnException method code snippet**

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        // If this is an ajax request, return the exception in the response
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            //If the session has expired, throws a SESSION TIMEOUT error
            if (Session["UserLogged"] == null)
            {
                //The hack mentioned before
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 502;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = new { success = false, errorType = "SESSION_TIMEOUT" ,error = filterContext.Exception.ToString() },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };  
            }
```

}

So, by using a simple $.Ajax Error Event, how would i retrive the data from the `filterContext.Result`? Specifically the `errorType` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to parse the JSON data out of the jqXHR responseText property in your error handler.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('jqXHR.responseText = ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
```

Comment: Added example to answer. From there you will need to parse the response for the json data. I'm not sure off the top of my head what the format would be.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I'll just a simple parse example to transform your answer on a full answer. But thanks anyway!